# HTML to emulate Vista Command Link?

Tags: html, windows-vista

This is a Windows Vista Command Link dialog:

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511455.commandlinks01(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511455.commandlinks01(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

I was wondering if anyone had already written HTML to mock the look and feel of the options in the dialog.

For my purposes, I only need the font and font size because I'm using an HTML-enabled Windows Forms control.  However, it might be more useful for the community at large if someone has a more complete solution suitable for use on websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Command Label is 12pt Segoe UI. The Supplemental Info is 9pt Segoe UI. Color for both is #003399 or RGB(0, 51, 153)